# pycharm - windows - "alt gr + {" opening project-structur instead inserting "{"

Tags: django, pycharm

i updated pycharm to 4.0.3 and i cannot insert `{` by <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>. it keeps opening Structure Panel (screenshot) instead of inserting `{`. anyone any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On which keyboard layout are you? I'm on the German one, and there it works with alt gr + {

Comment: i am on the german one. alt gr + { is not working. this is opening structure.

Comment: weird. I over read that you are on Windows though. With Ubuntu 14.04. its working with alt gr + {.

Comment: do you have also 4.0.3? could you pls test it on windows if you have one?

Comment: yeah I have 4.0.3 and no, I'm sitting on Linux here. But maybe just change the Hotkey for the structure as a workaround? https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: yeah but i dont see any "curly brace" in this keymaps. :(

Comment: that's of course true, just try to put the structure on another hotkey or just delete the hotkey completly

Comment: now i see, the update changed my keyboard configuration for pycharm. outside of pycharm alt gr + { is working. inside pycharm ``y`` is ``z`` which is english keyboard. i think this is the reason why alt gr + { isnot working

Comment: oh then { should be on shift ü.

Comment: i just needed to restart the pycharm and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

(if restarting Pycharm.exe doesn't work, like in my case, the following applies:)

I have Pycharm 2019.1, and I had the same problem with the Alt+Gr+any_key not working in Pycharm (but elswhere working fine).
-Win 10 
-error occured in whole Pycharm interface, while coding in python 3.7.0
-Europe

To fix this (at least in my case), just go to the following in Pycharm, and check the following box:
=>Help>Find Action...>registry> actionSystem.fix.alt.gr *check*

(: good luck :)